# Why some of the .jar files in an Android project does not have META-INF?

Tags: java, android, jar, android-studio

I have [downloaded](http://www.bixolon.com/html/en/download/download_product.xhtml?prod_id=18) .jar drivers for a portable printer and I have placed them under the libs folder at Android Studio 1.0.2. Normally other .jar files have this ▶ to right triange next to them but these ones don't. May be they need some kind of META-INF?

- Why Bixolon Printer has no triangles?
- Why I cannot import the com.bixolon?

[image: It seems like the .jar file is not recognized in the Android project. But why?]

Answer (score 1):

Not all jar files need a manifest.mf file. A manifest file is intended to make it possible to point an application to an entry point, so the .jar can be executed as a standalone application.

Other .jar files, however, are not meant to run on themselves. They are supposed to be class libraries, to be imported and used in other projects.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add those jars as libraries to your project; simply putting them under the "libs" folder is not sufficient. Specifically, you need to add something like this to your build.gradle:

```
compile files('libs/bixolon_printer.jar')
```

Once you do that, reimport your project in Android Studio.

Comment: This usually isn't true because wizard-generated build files have a build script statement to automatically pick up all .jar files in the libs folder.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are importing the right package.
I downloaded the same library and imported *"com.bxl"* instead of *"com.bix"*

[image: invalid import]

Try reading the printer's API and sample source. :)